# What does QA need to take into consideration while checking that tasks are valid

Tags: agile, team-management, development-process, team, requirements-engineering

I'm the QA lead in my company, and as part of that I'm responsible for the quality of the TASKS that each engineer has.

**What does it mean?** 
 I need to verify that each task/story/bug that assigned to one of the developers, as enough information, steps to reproduce, examples, definition of done etc. 
 
 So I wanted to ask you, what are your Key Indicators for verifying whether a ticket is comprehensive enough or not.

Comment: "I'm responsible for the quality of the TASKS that each engineer has" - Why not to simply ask the person?

Comment: because I think that it's not working. I wouldn't be in the office, they wouldn't be. I want to add something more sustainable.

Comment: Do you think the engineers cannot identify that some task requires more information, that they can do it, but cannot find out the information by themselves, or both?

Comment: I think that sometimes, some of the engineers, don't think enough about the task broadly enough. When the QA does it, he has more visibility to the product and, to what the customers feel, and to the breakable areas. That's why the QA has added value when going over the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

That is the job of the whole team in agile process. Firstly all of people involved in development process sit together and come up with Definition of ready, which is basically a checklist for task/story/bug which needs to be verified before the task/story/bug can go into development. They differ for each type and every development team / product so you'll need to define them by yourself. A good starting point is the [definition from scrum alliance](https://www.scruminc.com/definition-of-ready/):

- Definition of what needs to be done, which is understandable to all team members
- Has all necessary details (specs, design...) for it to be developed and tested succesfully

Answer (score 1):

Not answering the question directly, but using templates in tickets would help the author and you better understand what is expected and what is missing.

It really depends on the tool you are using for issue management, but it could be as simple as a text appearing in the body of the issue to actual fields, optionally populated with real values where applicable (e.g. version numbers), with a mandatory/optional setting